# Managed-Beans and Scopes - how to handle it?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, facelets

I want to do something like this: index.xhtml -> createPerson.xhtml -> addAddress.xhtml -> index.xhtml.

In Managed-Bean CreatePerson a new Person-Object will be created, filled and saved, in Managed-Bean AddAddress I need the Person-Object in order to add an address to this person and after this, it should navigate back to the starting point. I think, the Managed-Bean CreatePerson should be @SessionScoped, because I have to inject the Person-Object into AddAdress (here @ViewScoped).

I want to have a loop or rather the possibility to create more than one person, but how can I do this if I have a SessionScoped-Bean, that lives longer than I need it? Is there any command or annotation to destroy it? How do you handle such workflows related to the scopes?

I know about MyFaces Orchestra with conversation-scope, but I will, if possible, do it only with Eclipse/Tomcat (7.0.11)/Mojarra (2.0.3).

Answer (score 1):

Use a single view and make use of the `rendered` attribute to show/hide included views with "subforms" depending on each other. This way you can go with a `@ViewScoped` bean.

Alternatively, just save the `Person` in the DB after create and pass its `id` as request parameter to the next view and let it load from the DB again.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want (or can) use Tomcat and Mojarra then both solutions mentioned by BalusC work perfectly, although with the limitations that you have to stay on a single page or redo queries between page navigation. Your use case is exactly what the `conversation scope` in Java EE 6 (through CDI) is made for. You can add this too to Tomcat via the Weld reference implementation.

When using the method BalusC outlined for staying on a single page, to give the user a tiny bit the impression of dealing with separate pages, it might be an option to display the rendered parts of the page using 'dialogs' (floating, css, ...). If using a third party component library is an option for you, you could add RichFaces or PrimeFaces that both contain ready to use dialog components.